# Remove excess event properties sent from GTM to GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, analytics-events

When I send my events from GTM to GA4, at GA4 side I am able to see properties that I haven't specified as part of my event parameters.

Is there any way of removing these?

```
debug_mode 2

ga_session_id 2

ga_session_number 2

ignore_referrer 2

item_brand 2

page_location 2

page_referrer 2
```

apart from `item_brand` I haven't specified any of them.

Answer (score 1):

They are the default dimensions measured automatically. You can certainly override them from GTM by setting the event parameters with the reserved names of the default dimensions, but this may break certain reports or even data coherency.

We normally only override them when we need to enhance/sanitize the default values. An example would be removing query parameters from document location to make it easier to group by pages, or repopulating the referrer after it was erased by a redirection, say, from a CDN door.

Comment: So, it is not good to omit those default dimensions ?

Comment: Well, it's not like you can omit them. They're tracked by default, so nothing is required from you for them to be tracked as long as the gtag library is forming the calls. But yes, it's not good to tinker with them unless you know what you're doing.